# Strange javascript operator: expr >>> 0

Tags: javascript, numbers, operators

the following function is designed to implement the `indexOf` property in IE. If you've ever had to do this, I'm sure you've seen it before.

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf){

  Array.prototype.indexOf = function(elt, from){

    var len = this.length >>> 0;
    var from = Number(arguments[1]) || 0;

    from = (from < 0)
         ? Math.ceil(from)
         : Math.floor(from);

    if (from < 0)
      from += len;

    for (; from < len; from++){
      if (from in this &&    
          this[from] === elt)
        return from;
    }

    return -1;    
  };
}
```

I'm wondering if it's common to use three greater than signs as the author has done in the initial length check?

`var len = this.length >>> 0`

Doing this in a console simply returns the length of the object I pass to it, not true or false, which left me pondering the purpose of the syntax. Is this some high-level JavaScript Ninja technique that I don't know about? If so, please enlighten me!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Source:  [LINK](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/bitwise_operators.html)

> This is the zero-fill right shift
>   operator which shifts the binary
>   representation of the first operand to
>   the right by the number of places
>   specified by the second operand. Bits
>   shifted off to the right are discarded
>   and zeroes are added on to the left.
>   With a positive number you would get
>   the same result as with the
>   sign-propagating right shift operator,
>   but negative numbers lose their sign
>   becoming positive as in the next
>   example, which (assuming 'a' to be
>   -13) would return 1073741820:
>
> Code:
>
> ```
> result = a >>> b;
> ```

Comment: Wow, I was waaaaay off  : )  Thank you sir, I have been enlightened, you get the tick.

Comment: So what exactly is the effect of the usage in the example `var len = this.length >>> 0`? That would seem to do nothing.

Comment: Yes, but I was mainly just trying to figure out the usage in general. I can pretty much deduce from there what's going on.

Comment: If you can deduce that please share! I think what's most interesting about this question is not what the bit shift operator does, but why you might do it with zero as an operand.

Comment: Sorry, after reviewing the docs, I realize that I have NO clue what the operator is accomplishing in the example. Hopefully some high level ninja will come through with the details.

Comment: I have a guess which is that the intent is the same as `var len = this.length || 0` e.g. if the length property does not exist then set len = 0.

Comment: @jamietre: The end result is that any value will be converted to a number. If it isn't able to be converted, the number will be 0. Also, any decimal places will be stripped away. It is similar to doing `~~this.length`. So `"123" >>> 0` will be `123`, or `123.45 >>> 0` will be `123`, or `"some unconvertable value" >>> 0` will be `0`.

Comment: Excellent explanation @RightSaidFred. `||` would not convert a truthy non-numeric value. And a handy javascript trick I never knew before.

Comment: @RightSaidFred in this case, isn't this overkill? We *know* that `this` in an array with a `length` property that returns whole, positive numbers...right?

Comment: @Michael Haren - while I'm sure my own implementation would start somewhere around line 25 of the mozilla code, I bet there are a number of possible conditions that could result in it being some non-array other than `null` (which is already checked). Somehow. Anyway, trust in mozilla. They know what's best for you.

Comment: @Michael: As @jamietre stated, it [appears to be based on code from Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#section_5), which is meant for general consumption, and is therefore coded for safety. In your personal code you probably wouldn't need to do this.

Comment: @jamietre @rightsaidfred I'm happy to rely on Mozilla's implementation, it'd just be nice to know *why* they do it that way.

Comment: I can't answer why the implementation is done the way it is, but what the >>> operator does on an over-simplified level is trim the right-most X positions from a binary number.

An example...  

10 >>> 1 = 5
This is because decimal 10 is represented in binary as 1010. The >>>  operator trims the last 1 position in this case, leaving 101 which back in decimal is 5.

Comment: The only thing I can assume is that since bitwise operators are usually very very fast, it is done this way thinking in regards to optimal performance. No overhead of calling a function or performing a boolean comparison or anything.

Answer (score 34):

`>>>` is the [Zero-fill right shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Unsigned_right_shift) operator. The `>>> 0` is an abuse of the operator to convert any numeric expression to an "integer" or non-numeric expression to zero. Here is what it does:

> This operator shifts the first operand the specified number of bits to
>   the right. Excess bits shifted off to the right are discarded. Zero
>   bits are shifted in from the left. The sign bit becomes 0, so the
>   result is always positive.

[Here is an explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) of the convert-to-integer behavior which applies to all bitwise operations:

> Bitwise operators treat their operands as a sequence of 32 bits (zeros
>   and ones), rather than as decimal, hexadecimal, or octal numbers.
>   [...] Bitwise operators perform their operations on such binary
>   representations, but they return standard JavaScript numerical values.

Together, these statements assert that `expr >>> 0` will always return a positive number as follows:

1. `expr` is cast to a 32-bit integer for bitwise operation
2. `>>> 0` has no effect (no bits are shifted)
3. The result is converted to a [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

Here are a few expressions and their outcome:

```
        1 >>> 0 // 1 -- Number cast to 32-bit integer then back to Number
      "1" >>> 0 // 1 -- String cast to 32-bit integer then back to Number
undefined >>> 0 // 0 -- failed cast yields zero
```

Other interesting cases:

```
      1.1 >>> 0 // 1          -- decimal portion gets it
       -1 >>> 0 // 4294967295 -- -1 = 0xFFFFFFFF
                //               Number(0xFFFFFFFF) = 4294967295
      "A" >>> 0 // 0          -- cast failed
    "1e2" >>> 0 // 100        -- 1x10^2 is 100
   "1e10" >>> 0 // 1410065408 -- 1x10^10 is 10000000000
                //               10000000000 is 0x00000002540BE400
                //               32 bits of that number is 0x540BE400
                //               Number(0x540BE400) is 1410065408
```

Note: you will notice that none of them return [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN).

Answer (score 8):

The `>>>` (right-shift) binary operator is simply shifting the right-most bits of a number a specified number of times, and padding with zeroes to the left.

Note: In the following examples, the number in braces after a number signals what base it's in. 2 is for binary, 10 for decimal.

For example, `4 >>> 1` would do:

```
4(10) = 100(2)

4(10) >>> 1(10) = 010(2) = 2(10)
        shift once to the right
```

Other examples:

```
4(10) >>> 2(10) = 100(2) >>> 2(10) = 001(2) = 1(10)

10(10) >>> 4(10) = 1010(2) >>> 4(10) = 0000(2) = 0(10)

15(10) >>> 1(10) = 1111(2) >>> 1(10) = 0111(2) = 7
```

The way I remember it is to move the necessary amount of bits to the right, and then write the number. Like, in the last example, I simply moved everything to the right once, so the result is 0111.

Shifting 0 times does...nothing. No idea why it's there.

Comment: This is wrong. Bitwise operations convert the number to a *signed* 32-bit integer, unless they are on the leftside of an unsigned right shift by `0`. In that case, the number is converted to an *unsigned* 32-bit integer.

Answer (score 2):

Behold the zero-fill right-shift operator.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Comment: Thank you kindly, but you were beaten to the punch! +1 for you though