# How to (a) extract and (b) remove bits from a 32-bit integer in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

So I am trying to follow the tutorials on BitMasks and Bit Manipulation I've seen like [this](https://50linesofco.de/post/2017-02-13-bits-and-bytes-in-javascript) but am not getting expected results.

```
var a = 0b11110000000000000000000000000000
var b = 0b10010000000000000000000000000000
var c = a & b
console.log(c.toString(2))
// ...
```

> The AND operator will only put a one in every position where all arguments had a one.

```
expected  0b10010000000000000000000000000000
received -0b01110000000000000000000000000000
```

[Here](https://www.codesdope.com/blog/article/set-toggle-and-clear-a-bit-in-c/) and other places show how to clear and set a single bit, but I am wondering about a range/span of bits.

1. How do I *select* the set bits in the pattern `0b11110000000000000000000000000000`. So anything that has `0b101101010101...` or any other first 6 digits would extract into a number like `0b1011010000...` or `0b101101`, where either the number was a 6-bit number, or a 32-bit number with all the trailing rhs values set to 0. This way I can do a single check against an integer to check if it has a specific pattern.
2. How to clear or *remove* those bits from the integer, so instead of ending up with the 6 lhs bits, I end up with the remaining 26 rhs bits.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Signed_32-bit_integers

Comment: The problem is again JS' ambiguity. Like JS' handling of strings and numbers, and the often (but not always) interchangability, you also have this with numbers. JS' bit operations are performed on (and return) 32-bit **signed** integers. `0b11110000000000000000000000000000` is parsed as the number `4026531840` which is too big for an int. This is a double, and the corresponding int is `-268435456`. You get that, when you do `0b1111<<28` for example, or using `const int = v => v|0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the similar problem when I was trying to calculate color hex.

You can use `>>> 0` to make the result unsigned, and then get its binary correctly.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11385688/10289265) for more explanation.

```js
var a = 0b11110000000000000000000000000000;
var b = 0b10010000000000000000000000000000;
var c = (a & b) >>> 0;
console.log(c.toString(2));
```